# Magento 2 override Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver how to solve?

Tags: magento2, price, overrides, plugin, preference

Hi I'm using Magento 2.

I'm trying to **override Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver** by adding a plugin or preference in the app/code folder but I can't make it work.

I need to **replace the function resolvePrice()** in

> Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver

with my custom code so it won't have any bug.

Answer (score 2):

There is an excellent answer to the plugin option of your questions here: [how magento getting configurable product lowest price of associated products?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135513/how-magento-getting-configurable-product-lowest-price-of-associated-products)

You can see the setup of the module and an aroundResolvePrice method/function

I have worked on this problem before and came to conclusion that it may not be possible to use a preference for ConfigurablePriceResolver.  I only say this because I could not get my extension to have any effect using a preference no matter how I tried it.  If somebody knows how I'd love to see that.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/146198)

Comment: The linked answer I provided shows him exactly how to setup the aroundResolvePrice plugin method that he requested.  The other half explains my suspicion that a preference can not be used on this type of class.

Comment: Perhaps it would have been better to leave this question without any suggestion for a solution like 90% of the dang questions here.  Really frustrating to be called out for helping @Jai, especially since you contributed NOTHING to this question. :)