# How Magento getting configurable product lowest price of associated products?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

In view page by default magento displaying lowest price of associated products.

I need to display highest price of associated products.
Any one have idea where the logic is reside. How to customize this behavior.

**update:**

**Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver**

```
/**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface|\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return float
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function resolvePrice(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface $product)
    {
        $price = null;
        foreach ($this->configurable->getUsedProducts($product) as $subProduct) {
            $productPrice = $this->priceResolver->resolvePrice($subProduct);
            $price = $price ? min($price, $productPrice) : $productPrice;
        }
        if (!$price) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Configurable product "%1" do not have sub-products', $product->getName())
            );
        }
        return (float)$price;
    }
```

i'm trying to override this core file,but its not working.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver" type="Kensium\Catalog\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver" />
```

```
<?php
namespace Kensium\Catalog\Pricing\Price;
class ConfigurablePriceResolver extends \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface|\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return float
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function resolvePrice(\Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface $product)
    {
        $price = null;       
        $assPrice=array();
        foreach ($this->configurable->getUsedProducts($product) as $subProduct) {
            $productPrice = $this->priceResolver->resolvePrice($subProduct);
            $assPrice[]=$productPrice;
            $price = $price ? min($price, $productPrice) : $productPrice;
        }
        if (!$price) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('Configurable product "%1" do not have sub-products', $product->getName())
            );
        }
        return (float)(max($assPrice));
        //return (float)$price;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you want to show max price in details page?

Comment: yes in detail & listing also.when they change options at that time as usual.

Comment: in listing price are not changed, Have you checked, only one price is display

Comment: that is fine.customer should see max price of configurable product.

Comment: is this working for you? i have given example below for your requiements

Comment: @Rakesh,sorry for delay.will update you soon.thank you so much.

Comment: Please let me know if you have any issue. This is working code for display max price in details and listing page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You have to make plugin for that to display max price inside detail page,
Below is step by step module for your need,

Filepath,
**app/code/Vendor/Modulename/**

Registration file,
**app/code/Vendor/Modulename/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Modulename',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/Vendor/Modulename/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Modulename" setup_version="2.0.0">
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Modulename/etc/frontend/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver">
            <plugin name="pricemaxindetail" type="Vendor\Modulename\Pricing\ConfigurablePrice"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Modulename/Pricing/ConfigurablePrice.php**

Inside this file, you have to pluginize **resolveprice()** function

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Vendor\Modulename\Pricing;

class ConfigurablePrice
{
    protected $_moduleManager;
    protected $_jsonEncoder;
    protected $_registry;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Module\Manager $moduleManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,           
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,         
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory $productFactory,    
        \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable $configurableType,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\DataObjectHelper $dataObjectHelper,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockStateInterface $stockState,
        array $data = [] 
    )
    {
        $this->_moduleManager = $moduleManager;
        $this->_jsonEncoder = $jsonEncoder;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;      
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;       
        $this->_configurableType = $configurableType;        
        $this->dataObjectHelper = $dataObjectHelper;   
        $this->stockState = $stockState; 
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface|\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
     * @return float
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    public function aroundResolvePrice($subject, \Closure $proceed,\Magento\Framework\Pricing\SaleableInterface $product)
    {
        $price = null; 
        //get parent product id      
        $parentId = $product['entity_id'];
        $childObj = $this->getChildProductObj($parentId);
        foreach($childObj as $childs){
            $productPrice = $childs->getPrice();
            $price = $price ? max($price, $productPrice) : $productPrice;
        }
        return $price;        
        //return (float)$proceed($product['entity_id']);
    }

     public function getProductInfo($id){    
        //get product obj using api repository...          
        if(is_numeric($id)){           
            return $this->productRepository->getById($id); 
        }else{
            return;
        } 
    }

    public function getChildProductObj($id){
        $product = $this->getProductInfo($id);
        //if quote with not proper id then return null and exit;
        if(!isset($product)){
            return;
        }

        if ($product->getTypeId() != \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable::TYPE_CODE) {
            return [];
        }

        $storeId = 1;//$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $productTypeInstance = $product->getTypeInstance();
        $productTypeInstance->setStoreFilter($storeId, $product);
        $childrenList = [];       

        foreach ($productTypeInstance->getUsedProducts($product) as $child) {
            $attributes = [];
            $isSaleable = $child->isSaleable();

            //get only in stock product info
            if($isSaleable){
                foreach ($child->getAttributes() as $attribute) {
                    $attrCode = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
                    $value = $child->getDataUsingMethod($attrCode) ?: $child->getData($attrCode);
                    if (null !== $value && $attrCode != 'entity_id') {
                        $attributes[$attrCode] = $value;
                    }
                }

                $attributes['store_id'] = $child->getStoreId();
                $attributes['id'] = $child->getId();
                /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $productDataObject */
                $productDataObject = $this->productFactory->create();
                $this->dataObjectHelper->populateWithArray(
                    $productDataObject,
                    $attributes,
                    '\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface'
                );
                $childrenList[] = $productDataObject;
            }
        }

        $childConfigData = array();
        foreach($childrenList as $child){
            $childConfigData[] = $child;
        }

        return $childConfigData;
    }

}
```

run command

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

**remove var folder and check in frontend**

Comment: how to get this bounty for me?

Comment: already i marked as a right answer.i don't know some times bounty functionality not awarding properly.didn't get 100 points?

Comment: No, i didnt get but may be after expire periods of bounty, they can get, You haven't any option for that?

Comment: no.i marked as a right answer,so you should  get immediately.

Comment: @sivakumar you should click on "+100" to award bounty , you can check here for more info : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work

Comment: it's not working if the product have  group price.

Comment: How can we show price range for this like from $10 to $50 or $10 - $50?

Comment: Hi Rajesh its working for me but lowest and highest both price are showing can you help me regarding this ....i want to show only highest price ...

Comment: @RakeshJesadiya But when change currency, the same price is shown and different currency. This is a mistake

Comment: can you please relpy https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/250757/magento2-how-to-change-the-price-of-configurable-product-as-zero-in-product-view

Comment: Hi @RakeshJesadiya can u help me on this https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/309861/magento2-display-price-range-on-pdp-configrable-product

Comment: can we use the same concept to display the price range on pdp? pls advise

Answer (score 4):

See `\Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Pricing\Price\ConfigurablePriceResolver::resolvePrice`. It's method resposible for calculation the price of configurable product based on child price.

You can pluginize it and implements your algorithm.

Comment: instead of min can i use max ? is it enough?

Comment: I have checked that ,if you can use max its not display max price, its always show min price,

Comment: @Rakesh can you look at updated question once?

Comment: @KAndy i'm trying to plugnize ,but how to get child prices array. i think i need to rewrite the entire ConfigurablePriceResolver class?

Comment: hi @KAndy https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/296960/how-to-fetch-post-method-xml-data-in-magento2