# Magento2 How to change the price of configurable product as zero in product view page using js?

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, price

I want to show the configurable product price as **`zero`** instead of **`minimum price`** in product view page until options are selected. When all option of the product are selected then  only price has to change. Please help me how to do this by using jQuery in Magento 2?

In below image minimum price of the product is visible but i want zero in that place.
  [image]