# Default select option in product magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I have a configurable product.

I want to default select product have max price like this:
[image]

Any help? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To show the associated product with the `Max price` on the `Configurable product` detail page you need to create the plugin in your custom module.

Please check the below [post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135513/how-magento-getting-configurable-product-lowest-price-of-associated-products) and follow the steps mentioned in answer:

> **Ans**: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/136065

Hope this helps!